# Javascript: converting date/time from miliseconds to human-readable string?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

My AJAX call returns an object with a `Time` parameter. The problem is, it give it in a format like this:

```
2014-07-28T19:53:56.0000000Z
```

I want to turn this into a human-readable string. I've tried doing this:

```
var time = "2014-07-28T19:53:56.0000000Z";
var parsed = Date.parse(time).toLocaleString("en-us");
```

but that doesn't work (`parsed` evaluates to `"1,406,577,236,000"`)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You could checkout `Moment.js` and parse the String. With `Moment.js` you also have comprehensive output format options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try following way

```
   var time = "2014-07-28T19:53:56.0000000Z";
   var date = new Date(time);
   date.toString();
```

Comment: Both you and Nitin below are correct. Thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

try this way var time = new Date("2014-07-28T19:53:56.0000000Z"); After this you can convert this datetime in any local format